# Creating a table with pagination in a Node Edit form

Tags: 8, ajax, paging, page-controller

I have a content type `article` that has a field for Category. In order to help our editors find related articles, I included a table on the `article` Edit page that pulls in other `article` entities that have the same category as the current one.

I did this by implementing a `hook_form_alter` hook and adding some markup to the `$form` object after querying for all related articles.

```
// Query for matching articles
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'article');
$query->condition('field_articles_category.entity:taxonomy_term.tid', $categoryId);
$query->sort('created', $sortDirection);
$query->range($offset, $limit);
$query->latestRevision();

/* Omitting logic to load the Node objects by revision ID's */
// $articles is an array of Node objects of type article

$articlesTable = []
foreach ($articles as $index => $article) {
   $articlesTable[$index] ['articleTitle'] = [
      '#type' => 'link', '#title' => $article->getTitle(), '#url' => $article->toUrl()
   ]
}

$form['related_articles'] = [
   '#type' => 'details',
   '#title' => 'Articles of the Same category',
   'articlesTable' => $articlesTable
];
```

The table displays just fine and shows the expected articles. But there are sometimes hundreds of articles in a particular category so I would like to paginate this table for performance reasons (and to make sure the page is not too long to scroll through). How can I paginate such a table?

I've seen some articles mention creating a pagination controller and somehow setting the AJAX callback for that controller, but haven't found a concrete example yet to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tableselect` instead of `details` something like:

```
   $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n')
      ->condition('type', 'article', '=');
    $query->fields('n', ['nid']);
    $query->innerJoin('node__field_articles_category', 'category', 'category.field_articles_category_target_id = ' . $categoryId);
    //For the pagination we need to extend the pagerselectextender and
    //limit in the query
    $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')
      ->limit($limit);
    $article_ids = $pager->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $rows = [];
    foreach ($article_ids as $index => $article_id) {
      $article = Node::load($article_id->nid);
      $rows[$index + 1] = [
        'title' => $article->getTitle(),
        'url'   => Drupal::l($article->getTitle(), $article->toUrl()),
      ];
    }

    $form['related_articles']['table'] = [
      '#type'    => 'tableselect',
      '#header'  => ['title' => t('title'), 'url' => t('Url')],
      '#options' => $rows,
      '#empty'   => t('No users found'),
    ];
    // Finally add the pager.
    $form['related_articles']['pager'] = array(
      '#type' => 'pager',
    );
```

Result will be like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will still query all the contents (up to the `$limit`) at once, correct? My concern is if I have thousands of Articles, it will start to slow down rendering the edit page, which is why I was looking for a solution where next batch of contents are queried only when they are requested, instead of all at once.

Comment: You are welcome, now the query extend `PagerSelectExtender`,so for example if you set `$limit` to 10 the select will load 10 by 10 element.

Comment: Unfortunately, clicking  on a link in the pager (Next/Last, etc.) navigates away from the page and the  Editors loses any unsaved edits. That's why I was looking for an AJAX type solution.